# Mi Constante no esta definida

Tags: javascript, scraping, puppeteer

soy nuevo en javaScript y no entiendo por que me dice que mi variable no esta definida cuando si lo esta.

Mi codigo: "La Constante que lanza el error es User"

```
const Pupperteer = require('puppeteer');

//Las credenciales para ingresar a la universidad
const User = '19-MAET-6-001';
const Password = 'Esto es privado xd';

//Componentes necesarios
var UrlLogin = 'https://login.oymas.edu.do/v2/';
    //Campo usuario y contrasena
const IdTxbUser = '#user';
const IdTxbPass = '#password';

async function ScrapInformation(){
    
    const Browser = await Pupperteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });

    const Page = await Browser.newPage();

    await Page.goto(UrlLogin);

    await Page.$eval(IdTxbUser, el => {el.value = User});
}
```

Comment: Dónde llamas ScrapInformation(); ?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error exacto?

Comment: Ian Lopez, ScrapInformation() no lo puse en la pregunta por que no lo vi relevante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función que le pasas como segundo parámetro a `Page.$eval` se evalúa en el contexto de la página, no en el contexto desde donde tú la llamas. En ese contexto `User` no está definido.

Considerando que el signature de `Page.$eval` es:

```
 Page.$eval(selector, funcion, argumentos)
```

Tienes que usar el tercer parámetro, que es opcional, para inyectarle los valores que quieres considerar en ese contexto.

```
 Page.$eval(IdTxbUser, (el,userName) => {el.value = userName}, User);
```